# Can I access production accounts with iodocs or SDK applications with a non-certified integrator key in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header?

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi

As a developer or user, can I use [iodocs](https://iodocs.docusign.com) or DocuSign SDK applications with a non-certified integrator key in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header to access free Trial, Web, Pro or Enterprise level accounts?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a vendor's policy rather than programming.

Comment: As iodocs and the DocuSign SDK are developer tools and there are active question on this issue, it is topical and not policy but how the integrator key works for DocuSign developer tools if not certified. Thank your for your request for clarification.

Comment: Don Roby, hope those edits clarify the development ambiguity vs policy and make the question/answer more development focused

Comment: I'm sufficiently unsure of current SO thinking on this to retract my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the iodocs tool and any non-certified DocuSign Integrator Key application, like the  [DocuSign SDK samples at github](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK) will only allow access to sandbox/demo accounts created at the  [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center#form-devaccount)